# (Mass-)configure network interface for 802.1X EAP-TLS, no Windows Domain

Tags: windows-7, 802.1

I'm trying to prepare a decent amount of Windows 7 computers for wired 802.1X deployment.  I have it working already in a test setup, but I need automation.

There are two prerequisites; a) enabling a specific service; b) configuring 802.1X on the network interface (Interface properties -> authentication tab -> click this and that here and there).

I have the possibility to remotely run scripts as Administrator on said machines.

Now a) is easy to do while I'm struggling with an automated way to achieve b).

Before I turn to diff(1)-ing before and after registry dumps, I figured maybe someone here knows the general procedure to pull that off without having to manually do it on every computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it turns out there is `netsh` which can import/export interface configuration.